# YUP validation: array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, validation, yup

From an api rest I recover a data structure like this:

```
reasonForPayment: [
  "reasonForPayment string",
   "reasonForPayment string2"
]
```

With formik and yup I build the form, but I can't validate reasonForPayment consisting of 2 input fields.

I would need something like this:

[Example](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/09/28/react-formik-dynamic-form-example)

but the data to be returned must not be an array of objects but a simple array

Tips?

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question because I am having a hard time understanding it?

Comment: I call an api rest which returns me a json with that piece of code.

In the form I render 2 fields: reasonForPayment[0] and reasonForPayment[1]

I need to validate both with the required rule